# Как скомпилировать .py в .exe, чтобы файл открывался на всех версиях windows?

Tags: python, windows-10, windows-7, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

Я написал небольшую программу на Python, но когда я пытался пересобрать приложение в .exe с помощью auto py to exe, у меня на windows 10 все запускалось и работало правильно, но когда я решил поставить это же приложение на мой второй ПК (На windows 7) приложение не запускалось, Я прочитал что это из-за того, что на windows 7 Последняя поддерживаемая версия питона - это 3,9, а я писал свое приложение на версию 3,11. Есть ли способы либо создать один exe файл, работающий на всех версиях windows, либо несколько exe файлов для каждой версии?

Comment: Пересоберите файл на более старой версии

Comment: Версии python или Виндовс?

Comment: более старой версии python

Comment: А не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: точно так же, только на более старой версии.

Comment: Установите более старый Python, конкретно - 3.9. Проверяете, что ваша программа работает на этой версии. Дальше устанавливаете pyinstaller на эту версию Python. Пробуете собирать exe и тестируете на Windows 7.

Comment: Cпасибо за помощь!